# MobileConnect Best Practices for Short Codes

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

Are there any best practices around short codes? We are having an internal discussion around getting a single short code versus multiple short code. The line of thinking is a single short code for brand consistency versus multiple short codes for line of business branding or process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is a matter of perspective in terms of the needs you phase -
 and potentially keyword availability. If you insist on "Subscribe" as a keyword for two brands - if it's available - two shortcodes is required. There could also be a matter of having a permission / opt out strategy, e.g. having one shortcode for transactional and one for commercial (so lot of thoughts around it)

Generally speaking though, I believe that the fewer shortcodes the better. Ideally one. The reason is that opt-ins are handled at a Shortcode+Keyword level. Imagine you have a Subscription and Event list. That is 2 which needs to be maintained. If you add an additional shortcode, it would double the amount of lists, assuming you want the same.

However, answer could vary depending on the primary purpose of your SMS usage?

Comment: Thank you for your response. With the opt-ins being handled as a shortcode+keyword how does this work with opt-outs. My understanding was STOP or whatever keyword is used, is an opt-out for the entire short code regardless of the keyword?

Comment: There is an account wide (e.g. Stop) and then you Can do keyword specific opt outs :)